# How to draw lines with fountain pen effect in Unity?

Tags: unity, shaders, graphic-effects

I'm working on drawing lines in `Unity`, I've already implemented smooth line drawing with `LineRenderer`. But I need lines have effect of fountain pen or gel ink pen, just as the picture showed below, I have no idea about this,  may shaders  make the effect ?can anyone help?

**Now I can draw common lines with `Unity`:**

[image: Common Lines by Unity]

**Effect needed:**

[image: By Paper app]

Answer (score 1):

If you can find areas where the derivative is reasonably high (direction changes quickly) and make this thicker, and then slowly reduce thickness until you reach another, that might work.

No idea how to implements this in unity
, but thats’s my General thought.